# Windows 8/Windows Phone 8 app submission automation

Tags: selenium, automation, windows-store, windows-phone-store

I want to automate the process of app submission (both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 apps). To be exact, I want to automate some steps like logging in, filling the forms about the app out, and so on. Are there any software/script thingies, which provide such a functionality (first straightforward thing which comes to my mind is Selenium automation, but I am searching for some specific software)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, it seems that you'll have to wait for the promised Windows Store unification to have features like shown in this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/02/13/submitting-your-windows-8-apps.aspx